# what is this ant-sized black insect?

Tags: entomology, species-identification, pest-control

I have found these tiny ant-sized black bugs on the floor that are a little hard to kill; I have to hit them with so much force otherwise they stick to the back of my sandals alive! or i have o squeeze them hard between the Kleenex. 
Can anyone identify these please so i know how to get rid of them. 
I live in Asia, Iran by the way, thanks.

[image]

Comment: In the edit box there is an icon for inserting pictures to your posts. Please Click that and then drag and drop the photo there so that it will be displayed on the site and not require people to click through to the image.

Comment: I don't think you can get a proper species-id based on that picture. It looks like a beetle though.

Comment: Can you try taking a higher quality image?

Comment: Generic poisons usually work. And they're cheap enough to try.